# Searching for alpha characters in a column in excel

Tags: excel, python-2.7, spss

I have a number of excel files from other sources, and I need to check that they haven't accidentally put an alpha character in a numeric field. Not all variables are numeric only, and I can't simply purge alpha characters.

How can I flag those cases so that I can bring it to the attention of those sending the data.?

Comment: Sorry pnuts I should have been more clear! I am using python 2.7 (through enthought canopy). I put SPSS as a tag because eventually this data is going to be put through SPSS, so if there was a way to do it straight from there, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do what I think you require.
Add it to a normal module in the VBA editor and run the macro called **catchmixedvals**

The code assumes the following (but you can change these to suit):

Data is in a Sheet called "Data"

The data starts in cell "A3"

Cells containing 'mixed' data will be filled Red

The data is left intact

```
Sub catchmixedvals()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim stRow As Long, stCol As Long
Dim enRow As Long, enCol As Long
Dim drng As Range
Dim cl As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Data")
stRow = 3
stCol = 1

    With ws1
        'determine data range
        enRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, stCol).End(xlUp).Row
        enCol = .Cells(stRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set drng = Range(.Cells(stRow, stCol), .Cells(enRow, enCol))
            'examine each cell in data range
            For Each cl In drng
            On Error Resume Next
                If IsNumeric(cl) Then
                    'do nothing its a number
                Else
                    'a text cell therefore check for digits
                    For i = 1 To Len(cl)
                        If Mid(cl, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(cl, i, 1) <= "9" Then
                            cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next cl

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much barryleajo this is absolutely fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ISTEXT()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/check-if-a-cell-contains-text-HP003056106.aspx) to see if a cell contains text or you can use conditional formatting on a range and see if it is between 'A' and 'Z' and if it is format the background color like so:

[image]

Comment: This is helpful Bijan thank you! Because I am checking for text in many columns in the same file, and I have many files, is there a way to do this with an automated process?

Comment: You could 'automate' it using a macro/vba from within Excel.

Comment: @lbug are your data fields likely to contain composite alpha/numeric data e.g. 2c3 or 3a?

Comment: @Barryleajo these fields SHOULD be either all alpha or all numeric, but the people submitting the data often make mistakes. I can't simply remove invalid characters from fields when there is a mistake, I need to flag the cases somehow.

Comment: @hd1: Answers do not always involve code so long as it provides a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perform an arithmetic operation on the field and catch the exception to skip/flag it

Comment: This is not an answer but a suggestion. It would better be fit as a comment under the original post.